# Generating new rows in Spotfire based on start/end date

Tags: spotfire

First post.
I'm currently very new to Spotfire, but am struggling with something that seems like it should have an easy solution and I cannot make it work.

I have a data set for daily delivered volumes by contract through time, determined by the contract's start and end date (historic and future dates), where each contract can have multiple origination and delivery points and volume mix (or 1x1 relationships), but the same start and end date and cost.

How do I populate new rows through time for the days between the start and end date?  I can unpivot the data to do a Gantt chart visualization, but I need to be able to do multiple calculations off the daily delivered volumes.

[image: Dummy]

I've seen solutions for this here in R, but that's beyond my skill set.

Thank you,
Karl